# Trouble in searching from listView

Tags: android

In my application I am fetching the contact details and listing in the listView and I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter for getting the contact details. The problem is I want to add a Search option to my contact list.

The code I used for this is

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor; 
MatrixCursor dummyMatrixCursor;
int index = 0;
String FILENAMENAME = "Name.txt";
String FILENAMENAME2 = "name1.txt";

String FILENUMBER   =  "number.txt";
String FILENUMBER1   =  "number1.txt";

String value;

OpenHelper db_obj;

EditText inputSearch;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listcontact);

    inputSearch   =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


    value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("First");
    System.out.println("The Value"+value);

    // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
    mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );
    dummyMatrixCursor  =  new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"id","name","homephone","mobilenumber","workphone","homeemail","workemail","company"});

    // Adapter to set data in the listview
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.lv_layout,
            null,
            new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
            new int[] { R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

    // Getting reference to listview.
    final ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

    // Setting the adapter to listview.
    lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);        

    // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts.
    ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

    // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts.
    listViewContactsLoader.execute(); 

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ContactListerClass.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

    lstContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("You CLicked me");
            System.out.println(mMatrixCursor);

            if (mMatrixCursor.moveToPosition(arg2)){


                      String data = mMatrixCursor.getString(mMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                      System.out.println(data);

                      String data2 = mMatrixCursor.getString(mMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("details"));
                      System.out.println("The Details are"+data2);




                 if(dummyMatrixCursor.moveToPosition(arg2)){

                     String data1111 = dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                     System.out.println(".............."+data1111);


                     String dummyhomephone       =       dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("homephone"));
                     System.out.println("....."+dummyhomephone);

                     String  mobilenumberdummy   =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("mobilenumber"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+mobilenumberdummy);

                     String  workphonedummy      =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("workphone"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+workphonedummy);

                     String  dummyhomeemail      =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("homeemail"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+dummyhomeemail);

                     String  dummyworkemail      =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("workemail"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+dummyworkemail);

                     String  dummycompany        =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("company"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+dummycompany); 

                     String  dummyworkphone      =        dummyMatrixCursor.getString(dummyMatrixCursor.getColumnIndex("workphone"));
                     System.out.println("..................."+dummyworkphone); 

                        String details = "";


                        // Concatenating various information to single string
                        if(dummyhomephone != null && !dummyhomephone.equals("") )
                            details = " HomePhone : " + dummyhomephone + "\n";  
                        if(mobilenumberdummy != null && !mobilenumberdummy.equals("") )
                            details += " MobilePhone : " + mobilenumberdummy + "\n";
                        if(workphonedummy != null && !workphonedummy.equals("") )
                            details += " WorkPhone : " + workphonedummy + "\n";

                        if(dummyhomeemail != null && !dummyhomeemail.equals("") )
                            details += " HomeEmail : " + dummyhomeemail + "\n";
                        if(dummyworkemail != null && !dummyworkemail.equals("") )
                            details +=  " WorkEmail : " + dummyworkemail + "\n";
                        if(dummycompany != null && !dummycompany.equals("") )
                            details += " CompanyName : " + dummycompany + "\n";

                    db_obj   =    new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());


                    if(value.equals("First"))
                    {
                        //Inset Value into the first database....
                        db_obj.contact_insertionfirst(data1111,details);

                        //Write the first name to the text.
                        FileOutputStream fos1;
                            try {
                                fos1 = openFileOutput(FILENAMENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos1.write(data1111.getBytes());
                                System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"  + data1111);
                                fos1.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //Write the number to the Text
                            FileOutputStream fos2;
                            try {
                                fos2 = openFileOutput(FILENUMBER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos2.write(mobilenumberdummy.getBytes());
                                System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"  + mobilenumberdummy);
                                fos2.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }
                    else{
                        //Insert value into the second database
                        db_obj.contact_insertionSecond(data1111,details);

                        //Write the second name to text.
                        FileOutputStream fos1;
                            try {
                                fos1 = openFileOutput(FILENAMENAME2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos1.write(data.getBytes());
                                System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"  + data1111);
                                fos1.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //Write the number to the Text
                            FileOutputStream fos2;
                            try {
                                fos2 = openFileOutput(FILENUMBER1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos2.write(mobilenumberdummy.getBytes());
                                System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"  + mobilenumberdummy);
                                fos2.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                 }

                }
            mMatrixCursor.close();

            ContactListerClass.this.finish();
            Intent  returnIntent  =   new Intent();
            returnIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(returnIntent);
        }
    });

}    

/** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>{     

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
        Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null, 
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

        if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));


                Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
                // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact 
                Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null, 
                                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId, 
                                        null, null);


                String displayName="";
                String nickName="";
                String homePhone="";
                String mobilePhone="";
                String workPhone="";
                String photoPath="" + R.drawable.tfff;
                byte[] photoByte=null;
                String homeEmail="";
                String workEmail="";
                String companyName="";
                String title="";



                if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    // Getting Display Name
                    displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                    do{

                        // Getting NickName
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                            nickName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                        // Getting Phone numbers
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME : 
                                    homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE : 
                                    mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK : 
                                    workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;  
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting EMails
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ) ) {                                    
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME : 
                                    homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK : 
                                    workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;                                      
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting Organization details
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        }

                        // Getting Photo    
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){                               
                            photoByte = dataCursor.getBlob(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data15"));

                            if(photoByte != null) {                         
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                                // Getting Caching directory 
                                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                                // Temporary file to store the contact image 
                                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+contactId+".png");

                                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.flush();

                                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                            }

                        }

                    }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());                    

                    String details = "";

                    // Concatenating various information to single string
                    if(homePhone != null && !homePhone.equals("") )
                        details = "HomePhone : " + homePhone + "\n";  
                    if(mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("") )
                        details += "MobilePhone : " + mobilePhone + "\n";
                    if(workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkPhone : " + workPhone + "\n";
                    if(nickName != null && !nickName.equals("") )
                        details += "NickName : " + nickName + "\n";
                    if(homeEmail != null && !homeEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "HomeEmail : " + homeEmail + "\n";
                    if(workEmail != null && !workEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkEmail : " + workEmail + "\n";
                    if(companyName != null && !companyName.equals("") )
                        details += "CompanyName : " + companyName + "\n";
                    if(title != null && !title.equals("") )
                        details += "Title : " + title + "\n";

                    // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                    mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,photoPath,details});
                    dummyMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,homePhone,mobilePhone,workPhone,homeEmail,workEmail,companyName});
                }

            }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return mMatrixCursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {           
        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
        mAdapter.swapCursor(result);
    }       
}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent in =new Intent();
in.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But even after inseting the value in the edit text no change at all.
Somebody please help me to sort it out fastly

Comment: what error you face.??

Comment: No errors just the code is not serving my purpose!!! :(

Comment: give your whole code..

Comment: yeah sure I will update it

Comment: Will be a quiet difficult job bcoz its quiet one big class :(

Comment: we should discussion in chat..

Comment: your requirement not full feel because you are getting contacts from DB. and also search contacts from DB. instead of that just get all contact from DB to array list one time. and search from array list.

Comment: No I am not getting it from db..just inserting the selected contact to the database

Comment: @Geethu you are getting from db..

Comment: @Geethu dhaval is right. try that way. it will sure solve your problem.

Comment: these may help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Charan Pai Thanks for your link I will check this out